# How to make an array of strings stored in a vector

Tags: c++

I am trying something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string inputStr;
    vector <string> strVector;
    cin.getline(inputStr,200);
    int i=0;
    while (inputStr!=NULL){ //unless all data is read.
        strVector[i]=getline(inputStr," ");
        i++;
    }//while.

    for (int j=0; j<strVector.size(); j++){
        cout<< strVector[j];
        cout<<endl;
    }
} //main.
```

Any one who can help. I am trying to store my input string in `vector` string and then I can push_back my ith string.

Comment: Try to use `push_back` method: `strVector.push_back(getline(inputStr, " "));`

Comment: Right... Your syntax is valid for a std::map but not a std::vector. Use push_back.

Comment: can I ask the apparently not-so-obvious question? what is `getline(inputStr," ")` doing? If you're looking to simply load a vector with whitespace-seperated strings from `cin` there are simpler ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Much of your code involving inputString is invalid.  There is no getline member of `istream` that takes a `std::string`, so this is invalid:

```
cin.getline(inputStr,200);
```

What you want there instead is the global getline:

```
getline(cin, inputStr);
```

Second, there is no global getline which reads directly from a `std::string`, so this is invalid:

```
strVector[i]=getline(inputStr," ");
```

What you want to use there is an `istringstream`.  Altogether, your code might look something like this:

```
std::getline(std::cin, inputStr);
std::istringstream iss(inputStr);
std::string word;
// read from the istringstream until failure
while (std::getline(iss,word,' '))
    strVector.push_back(word);
```

If you want to delimit on whitespace(including tabs) then you can use `operator>>` instead of getline.

Comment: +1 and/or an `istream_iterator` around `iss` with a `back_inserter` to shove strings into strVector.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley ..
can you explain with comments what are your trying to do in 2nd line with istringstream.

Comment: @AzkaAhmad: I would, but I have to leave just now.  Take a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).  Or perhaps someone else will explain.

Comment: @AzkaAhmad This is pulling a full-line read from (cin), then loading it into a stringstream to extract space-separated content into individual strings that are then pushed into your vector. I hope that made sense. This is what allows you to type multiple words in a single line, hit enter, then have those words split into single strings and collected in your vector.

Comment: @WhozCraig
Do I need to add a library for this istringstream
because in PUTTY I am getting this error
 "variable âstd::istringstream issâ has initializer but incomplete type"

Comment: `#include <sstream>` is probably what you're missing.

Comment: @WhozCraig 
If I am using istringstream iss() in a while loop. Ans in this while loop, in each iteration, I have to store new data in iss, would it cause SEGMENTATION FAULT or not. And One thing more, if do..vector.clear(), then all elem are deleted, but vector still exists right ?????

Comment: @AzkaAhmad The code above is designed to be in a while loop. Regarding a vector clear, it removes all the elements and releases the storage space allocated to hold them all (as far as you know). If you have further questions unrelated to Benjamins's answer you may with to either update your main question above or accept and answer here and create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/) method of the `std::vector` template

Answer (score 0):

Here is nother way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string> strVec;
    string str;
    cout<<"Enter # to quit \n\n";
    int i=0;


    while (str!="#")
    {  
        cout<<"Input text No. "<<i+1 <<" here > ";
        cin>>str ;
        strVec.push_back(str);


        i++;
    } 

    cout<<"\nStored text\n----------\n";
    for (int j=0; j<strVec.size()-1; j++)    cout<<j+1<<"  "<< strVec[j]<<"\n";


    cout<<"\n\n";

    return(0);
}
```